# Xamarin.Forms isn't changing media

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.forms, storyboard, launch-screen

I'm doing:
[Xamarin Forms App Icon Correct way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbKrbv9h_ZE),
[Launch Screens for Xamarin.iOS Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=macos)

On simulator all working good, but when i run Visual Studio from Windows with my iPhone, it wasn't working. Just nothing doesn't change.

Comment: Could you provide some more information ?

Comment: Need to use MacOS, Visual Studio for MacOS and Xcode.
Perhaps, on Windows we can't do it